# Save user credentials from one app and use it from another Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, single-sign-on, android-contentprovider, user-accounts

I have 3 apps. Each app has a login activity. When I login to the first app, the username and the access token should get saved and when the user opens the next app, he should automatically be logged in using the saved credentials from the first app.

To do this, I came across the concept of `ContentProviders`. But I am not really sure how to  use it with my scenario.

Initially, I was using a service to save the user email in the Accounts app of the device and it could be accessed from other apps. But I also need to save the access token.

How can i achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you are login with first app then create a file write credentials in file and store it in internal storage when your other app start get data from file and set in your login screen.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have any examples with the same?

Comment: try this http://www.journaldev.com/9383/android-internal-storage-example-tutorial                          https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html